# laravel quiz app isn't working properly, can anyone tell me a solution?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-artisan, laravel-migrations

I want to create quiz app, I did this but I have some problems, when I click any radio button it isn't working properly, because the result isn't correct, when I mark first answer, this answer cancels in the second question. So if the last question answer is correct, total score will be 1, if it is incorrect total score will be 0. Please tell me solution! Thank you in advance!
there is blade.php

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{route('check_quizz')}}">
                    <div>
                        @foreach($quizzes as $quizz)
                            <br><p>{{$quizz->question}}</p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="{{$quizz->answer_1}}" id="{{$quizz->answer_1}}">
                                <label for="{{$quizz->answer_1}}">A. {{$quizz->answer_1}}</label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="{{$quizz->answer_2}}" id="{{$quizz->answer_2}}">
                                <label for="{{$quizz->answer_2}}">B. {{$quizz->answer_2}}</label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="{{$quizz->answer_3}}" id="{{$quizz->answer_3}}">
                                <label for="{{$quizz->answer_3}}">C. {{$quizz->answer_3}}</label>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="{{$quizz->answer_4}}" id="{{$quizz->answer_4}}">
                                <label for="{{$quizz->answer_4}}">D. {{$quizz->answer_4}}</label>
                            </p>

                         @endforeach
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                    <div class="box-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

there is migrations

```
Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->text('question');
        $table->integer('answer_1');
        $table->integer('answer_2');
        $table->integer('answer_3');
        $table->integer('answer_4');
        $table->boolean('is_correct');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
```

[There is my project view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HACYB.png)

[There is my blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G7NK.gif)

Comment: you named all the radio fields the same name for every quiz/question, `q1`, so they are all in the same radio group

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using the same name for radio buttons for all quiz records

Try to name them with the quiz id as identifier

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{route('check_quizz')}}">
    <div>
        @foreach($quizzes as $quizz)
            <br><p>{{$quizz->question}}</p>
                <p>
                    <input type="radio" name="{{$quizz->id}}-q1" value="{{$quizz->answer_1}}" id="{{$quizz->answer_1}}">
                    <label for="{{$quizz->answer_1}}">A. {{$quizz->answer_1}}</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="radio" name="{{$quizz->id}}-q1" value="{{$quizz->answer_2}}" id="{{$quizz->answer_2}}">
                    <label for="{{$quizz->answer_2}}">B. {{$quizz->answer_2}}</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="radio" name="{{$quizz->id}}-q1" value="{{$quizz->answer_3}}" id="{{$quizz->answer_3}}">
                    <label for="{{$quizz->answer_3}}">C. {{$quizz->answer_3}}</label>
               </p>
               <p>
                   <input type="radio" name="{{$quizz->id}}-q1" value="{{$quizz->answer_4}}" id="{{$quizz->answer_4}}">
                   <label for="{{$quizz->answer_4}}">D. {{$quizz->answer_4}}</label>
               </p>

       @endforeach
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
    <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @GiorgiGegechkori Glad I could help. If the answer solves your issue pls remember to mark it as accepted/upvote for the benefit of subsequent visitors